# GCC Segfault in function template with thread_local variable within internal structure

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

Perhaps best to get to the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T& f) {
        struct auto_logger {
            ~auto_logger() {
                static thread_local vector<char> b; // Segfault here
            }
        } inst;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    A a;
    vector<char> b;
    a.foo(b);
}
```

The above code (which I think is valid?) compiles okay if `foo()` is not a template, however as it stands, this causes GCC to segfault. Probably is a compiler bug - but would like to know if I'm doing something wrong?

The idea is I want to execute something always when that function exits (even with an exception - unless there's a better way?)

I tested on coliru and locally with 5.2.1... Seems to compile fine on clang though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it actually seems to be a valid bug report rather than a question. Please file it as a bug report, if such one doesn't exist yet.

Comment: To answer your question: If source code makes your compiler segfault, your compiler has a bug.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I couldn't find one on bugzilla; I guess my point was to check I'm not doing anything stupid before I blame the compiler - as often, this is the case...

Comment: agreed, that is good style, but programs should never segfault, simple as that, especially not if they are compilers and what you feed them is parse-syntactically correct source code. Admittedly, I'm not sure if "staticality" and thread-locality are concepts I'd mix, but it shall never make your compiler crash.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - what do you mean "staticality" and "thread-locality" are two you won't mix? (AFAIK, `thread_local` *implies* `static` - unless explicitly stated as `static` <- i.e. more for "documentation"..)

Comment: I have compiled your code in `gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)`, by adding a printing statement inside `~auto_logger()`. For me it is compiled as well as executed successfully.